# How can I make a complex object hollow inside?

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-printing, solidify-modifier

I've been modeling GT wing for a car to 3D print and I want to model the inner structure in order to print in 4 separate pieces(since it is too large to print in one go).[image: Modeled GT wing]
And I've been trying to make it so that the wing has a thin wall but hollow inside for material and weight saving that looks something like the picture below but with the GT wing if that makes sense.
[image: Bridge edge loop applied to a cylinder]
I've tried converting it to a solid model and made it into a shell model with [FreeCAD](https://www.freecad.org/) software and using a modifier like Solidify Modifier to make it a shell-like model for the past few months but none of them worked unfortunately. Solidify modifier seemed to be a somewhat promising method but then a complex model like this makes the mesh intersect with itself when the modifier is applied.
[image: Solidifiy modifier applied]
[image: Close up of one of many intersecting parts]
Is there any way of getting away with this self-intersecting problem or a completely different solution to make it a shell-like model?

[image]

Comment: can you share your blende file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: I've added it just now!

Comment: I have no 3D printer myself, but friends of mine do and what I've seen there when trying to print something is that in the printer software you can choose how thick the wall should be and if the object is completely hollow, filled with some structure or completely solid. So I'm wondering if it is really necessary to deal with this in Blender since you don't need it for the model on its own but just for 3D printing. Although the solution might help people who need this for the model itself even though it's a very specific solution presumably only applicable on this object.

Comment: Yes, it is actually necessary in certain aspects. Slicer has this mode called vase mode where it basically prints the outer wall of the object exactly as you explained, also, as you stated already, you could do it by turning off the infill setting too. But what I want to achieve here is that I want to make an inner structure so that I can connect all separate parts after the prints with long shafts or smth. The problem here is that if you turn off the infill setting, it also doesn't fill in the inner structure parts where I want to be durable. Hope that explains the issues! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right path with the Solidify Modifier. Just set the *Offset* to $1$ instead of the default $-1$. *Offset* of $-1$ extrudes inwards but your geometry is too dense already hence it starts intersecting so it's best to extrude outwards with offset positive 1.

But of course this will change the outer dimensions and modify the outer roundness. Your problem is those 2 [`Edge Loops`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html) at the top and 2 at the bottom, so I would dissolve those 4 Edge Loops with <kbd>X</kbd> *> Dissolve Edges*.

[image]

Temporarily remove the *Subdivision Modifier* and *Mirror Modifier* and then, add and [`Apply`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html) a *Solidify Modifier* with mode *Complex*. Now you can add those [`Edge Loops`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html) back again with [`Loop Cuts`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>:

[image]

And add 2 supporting Loop Cuts.

[image]

Now you can add the *Mirror Modifier* and *Subdivision Modifier* back again.

[image]

Comment: Although this is the only solution that even I was able to think of, the person wants to print the model. In that case something like this will mess up the dimensions (right?). Is there a way to keep the -1 but still avoid the issues ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But yes, exactly as Akshay pointed out, I would like the model to be thickened inward in order not to mess with the dimension as well as the sharpness of the corners... :'(

Comment: yes good point. I updated the answer for what I would do instead.

Comment: Thank you very much Harry! You really are a lifesaver! 
It worked perfectly as I always expected it to!

Comment: @Brian you're welcome! I'm glad it worked out for you! Just double check if the mirroring worked as well i forgot about it lol

Comment: Yes! When I checked, the lower corner also had the intersection but I was able to get rid of it with your approach! And the mirror modifier also works just fine! Much appreciated :)))